# Using a signal to create a new instance of a model when another models field changes

Tags: django, signals, models

I'm trying to create a new `ChatRoom` whenever an `Offer accepted` field changes to `True` a Chatroom would be created for that Offer. What I did is a function that checks if an `accepted` field turns into a `True` so then it creates a `ChatRoom`. And then a `post_save` signal that creates the ChatRoom model and hook the fields together.

The problem is it works BUT only for the first `Offer` that has it's accepted field True. When tested it out, and changed the accepted field in another `Offer` to `True` I get the following error:

`get() returned more than one Offer -- it returned 2!`

Here are my models:

```
class Offer(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
    comment = models.TextField()
    accepted = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.comment)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Offers"


class ChatRoom(models.Model):
    offer = models.ForeignKey(Offer)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Chat Rooms"
```

The function that I have used:

```
def create_chatroom_on_offer_accepted(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if Offer.objects.get(accepted=True):
        ChatRoom.objects.create(offer=instance, title="Chatroom")

post_save.connect(create_chatroom_on_offer_accepted, sender=Offer)
```

Now the way I understand the error is that, it's trying to create a `ChatRoom` but it doesn't actually know which `Offer` exactly to choose from since there are 2.

How would I make sure that it knows the `Offer accepted` field that it's going to create the `ChatRoom` from? 
I thought of a custom `save()` function in the `Offer` model to detect the change in the field of `accepted` and that would trigger a `post.save()` signal to create a `ChatRoom` but I don't know exactly if that would work or not?

Comment: "Offer.objects.get(accepted=True)" will fail when there are more Offers with "accepted=True". I'm not really sure what you're trying to do. If you want to check if the instance has accepted=True just do "if instance.accepted"

Comment: @madprops By using `Offer.objects.get(accepted=True)` I want to check whenever `accepted` field have been changed to `True` to trigger the function and create a `ChatRoom`

Comment: What you are doing with that line is getting a record from a database. You are looking for an Offer that has accepted as True, any offer. And since there are more than 1 offer with accepted=True it fails, because .get fails when you get more than 1 result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
if Offer.objects.get(accepted=True):
```

to

```
if instance.accepted:
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you!